# How to make color overlay like in photoshop?

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I have an image and I want to make a color blend method like Photoshop's color overlay for this image. I just tried this algorithm at below but result is not like my exception. So how can I make that like Photoshop does.

I tried this algorithm:

```
var redOverlay = 255, greenOverlay = 0, blueOverlay = 0;
var redImage = new Image(fx.width, fx.height);
redImage.src = fx.src;
colorCanvas.width = redImage.width;
colorCanvas.height = redImage.height;
colorCanvasCtx.drawImage(redImage, 0, 0, redImage.width, redImage.height);
var pixelData = colorCanvasCtx.getImageData(0, 0, redImage.width, redImage.height);
for (var i = 0; i < pixelData.data.length; i += 4)
{
    pixelData.data[i]     = ((pixelData.data[i]     / 0.30) * redOverlay   / 255) + 1; // red
    pixelData.data[i + 1] = ((pixelData.data[i + 1] / 0.59) * greenOverlay / 255) + 1; // green
    pixelData.data[i + 2] = ((pixelData.data[i + 2] / 0.11) * blueOverlay  / 255) + 1; // blue
 }
 colorCanvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, redImage.width, redImage.height);
 colorCanvasCtx.putImageData(pixelData, 0, 0);
 redImage.src = colorCanvas.toDataURL();
```

This is my source image

[image: This is my source image]

This is what I got with this algorithm

[image: This is what I got with this algorithm]

This is what I expecting
[image: This is what I expecting]

Comment: Consider what result you get with a white source pixel (where the pixeldata is 255).

Comment: it's not about only white pixels https://imgur.com/a9FVaHP